# How is Zookeeper zk_max_latency calculated?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Hi I just took some stats off my zookeeper...

As you can see zk_max_latency is quite high. But is that the maximum it ever reached or is it always the current value?

```
echo mntr | nc localhost 2181
zk_version  3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 04:05 GMT
zk_avg_latency  0
zk_max_latency  4738
zk_min_latency  0
zk_packets_received 2387852
zk_packets_sent 2387928
zk_num_alive_connections    29
zk_outstanding_requests 0
zk_server_state follower
zk_znode_count  7973
zk_watch_count  74
zk_ephemerals_count 22
zk_approximate_data_size    12356979
zk_open_file_descriptor_count   62
zk_max_file_descriptor_count    16384
zk_fsync_threshold_exceed_count 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zk_max|avg|min_latency` metric is calculated starting from ZK server startup.

The `mntr` command is handled by [MonitorCommand](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/command/MonitorCommand.java#L49), which query the max/avg/min request metrics from [ZooKeeperServer.serverStats.requestLatency](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/ServerStats.java#L40)

```
ZKDatabase zkdb = zkServer.getZKDatabase();
ServerStats stats = zkServer.serverStats();

print("version", Version.getFullVersion());

print("avg_latency", stats.getAvgLatency());
print("max_latency", stats.getMaxLatency());
print("min_latency", stats.getMinLatency());
```

ServerStats.java

```
// getters
public long getMinLatency() {
    return requestLatency.getMin();
}

public double getAvgLatency() {
    return requestLatency.getAvg();
}

public long getMaxLatency() {
    return requestLatency.getMax();
}
```

And the request latency is updated at [ServerStats.updateLatency()](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/ServerStats.java#L137). The core implementation class is [AvgMinMaxCounter](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/metric/AvgMinMaxCounter.java).

```
public void updateLatency(Request request, long currentTime) {
    long latency = currentTime - request.createTime;
    if (latency < 0) {
        return;
    }
    requestLatency.addDataPoint(latency);
    if (request.getHdr() != null) {
        // Only quorum request should have header
        ServerMetrics.UPDATE_LATENCY.add(latency);
    } else {
        // All read request should goes here
        ServerMetrics.READ_LATENCY.add(latency);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I used a reset command and it's back to normal. So as you mention it's the max since startup.

Comment: The reset command can be given with `echo srst | nc {zk-host} {zk-port}`

Answer (score 1):

**zk_max_latency** :
The maximum time it took this ZooKeeper server to process a request in milliseconds.

No, this is measured since the last restart of the ZooKeeper server.